# Jackson throws a JsonParseException on Ajax call

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

I'm making an Ajan call to an endpoint in my controller, the parsing is handle by Jackson, the code for my method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkExistTemplate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Object checkExistTemplate(@RequestParam("name") final String templateName, final Model model,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws CMSItemNotFoundException
{

    final ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
    final ArrayNode result = new ArrayNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
    Boolean existTemplate = false;

    final CustomerData customer = getUser();
    final B2BUnitModel b2bUnit = getSessionB2BUnit();

    existTemplate = urreaTemplatesFacade.exitsTemplateFor(templateName, customer, b2bUnit);

    if (existTemplate == false)
    {
        node.put("message", "OK");
        node.put("status", AJAX_STATUS_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        node.put("status", AJAX_STATUS_ERROR);
    }

    final ObjectNode unit = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

    unit.put("existTemplate", existTemplate);

    result.add(unit);

    node.put("exist", result);

    return node;
}
```

Debugging shows my node object should look like this in JSON:

```
{"message":"OK","status":"0","exist":[{"existTemplate":false}]}
```

But I get a JsonParseException:

> GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet DispatcherServlet lanzÃ³
>   excepciÃ³n org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected
>   end-of-String when base64 content  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column:
>   -1]
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode._reportBase64EOF(TextNode.java:297)
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode.getBinaryValue(TextNode.java:105)
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode.getBinaryValue(TextNode.java:160)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:664)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:689)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.MapEntrySerializer.serializeDynamic(MapEntrySerializer.java:249)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.MapEntrySerializer.serialize(MapEntrySerializer.java:194)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.MapEntrySerializer.serialize(MapEntrySerializer.java:19)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IteratorSerializer.serializeContents(IteratorSerializer.java:95)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IteratorSerializer.serialize(IteratorSerializer.java:64)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IteratorSerializer.serialize(IteratorSerializer.java:13)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:689)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951)
>           at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286)
>           at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:301)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:390)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.btg.BTGSegmentFilter.doFilterInternal(BTGSegmentFilter.java:45)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.CartRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CartRestorationFilter.java:123)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.personalizationservices.filter.CxPersonalizationFilter.doFilterInternal(CxPersonalizationFilter.java:66)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:74)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilter(StorefrontFilter.java:75)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:100)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:71)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:201)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at com.urrea.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Looking at [the code in Jackson's git repository](https://github.com/codehaus/jackson/blob/master/src/mapper/java/org/codehaus/jackson/node/TextNode.java#L111), I located the class' method that throws the error:

```
/**
 * Method for accessing textual contents assuming they were
 * base64 encoded; if so, they are decoded and resulting binary
 * data is returned.
 */
public byte[] getBinaryValue(Base64Variant b64variant)
    throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayBuilder builder = new ByteArrayBuilder(100);
    final String str = _value;
    int ptr = 0;
    int len = str.length();

    main_loop:
    while (ptr < len) {
        // first, we'll skip preceding white space, if any
        char ch;
        do {
            ch = str.charAt(ptr++);
            if (ptr >= len) {
                break main_loop;
            }
        } while (ch <= INT_SPACE);
        int bits = b64variant.decodeBase64Char(ch);
        if (bits < 0) {
            _reportInvalidBase64(b64variant, ch, 0);
        }
        int decodedData = bits;
        // then second base64 char; can't get padding yet, nor ws
        if (ptr >= len) {
            _reportBase64EOF();
        }
        ch = str.charAt(ptr++);
        bits = b64variant.decodeBase64Char(ch);
        if (bits < 0) {
            _reportInvalidBase64(b64variant, ch, 1);
        }
        decodedData = (decodedData << 6) | bits;
        // third base64 char; can be padding, but not ws
        if (ptr >= len) {
            // but as per [JACKSON-631] can be end-of-input, iff not using padding
            if (!b64variant.usesPadding()) {
                // Got 12 bits, only need 8, need to shift
                decodedData >>= 4;
                builder.append(decodedData);
                break;
            }
            _reportBase64EOF(); // THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION GETS THROWN
        }
        ch = str.charAt(ptr++);
        bits = b64variant.decodeBase64Char(ch);

        // First branch: can get padding (-> 1 byte)
        if (bits < 0) {
            if (bits != Base64Variant.BASE64_VALUE_PADDING) {
                _reportInvalidBase64(b64variant, ch, 2);
            }
            // Ok, must get padding
            if (ptr >= len) {
                _reportBase64EOF();
            }
            ch = str.charAt(ptr++);
            if (!b64variant.usesPaddingChar(ch)) {
                _reportInvalidBase64(b64variant, ch, 3, "expected padding character '"+b64variant.getPaddingChar()+"'");
            }
            // Got 12 bits, only need 8, need to shift
            decodedData >>= 4;
            builder.append(decodedData);
            continue;
        }
        // Nope, 2 or 3 bytes
        decodedData = (decodedData << 6) | bits;
        // fourth and last base64 char; can be padding, but not ws
        if (ptr >= len) {
            // but as per [JACKSON-631] can be end-of-input, iff not using padding
            if (!b64variant.usesPadding()) {
                decodedData >>= 2;
                builder.appendTwoBytes(decodedData);
                break;
            }
            _reportBase64EOF();
        }
        ch = str.charAt(ptr++);
        bits = b64variant.decodeBase64Char(ch);
        if (bits < 0) {
            if (bits != Base64Variant.BASE64_VALUE_PADDING) {
                _reportInvalidBase64(b64variant, ch, 3);
            }
            decodedData >>= 2;
            builder.appendTwoBytes(decodedData);
        } else {
            // otherwise, our triple is now complete
            decodedData = (decodedData << 6) | bits;
            builder.appendThreeBytes(decodedData);
        }
    }
    return builder.toByteArray();
}
```

Since my JSON is valid, why am I getting this error?

Comment: I'm experiencing a the same error. Did you ever find a solution?